# Add Double Quotes to csv File

Tags: c#, .net, regex, csv

I Have csv file , what I'm supposed to do is to add double quotes if the cell doesn't contain it , else don't . This is my C# Code

```
 foreach (var item in csv.GetFieldHeaders())
                {

                    dataColumn = dataColumn + "\"" + item + "\"" + ',';
                }
                writer.WriteLine(dataColumn.Substring(0, dataColumn.Length - 1));
                dataColumn = string.Empty;
                //Iteratively loop through all the Rows in the File and Append quotes to it
                string str;

                while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < csv.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        str = csv[i];
                        if (csv[i].Length == 0)//if the column don't have any data
                        {
                            dataColumn = dataColumn + csv[i] + ",";
                        }

                        else
                            dataColumn = dataColumn + "\"" + csv[i].Replace("\"", "'").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", "").Replace(" ", "()").Replace(")(", "").Replace("()", " ") + "\"" + ",";
                    }
                    row.Append(dataColumn.Substring(0, (dataColumn.Length) - 1));//-1 to exclude the comma (,) at the end of the row
                    writer.WriteLine(row);//Write to File
                    dataColumn = null;
                    row.Clear();
                }

            }
```

Now I Have a cell say 
**"open anchor tag href="http://abc.html" target="_blank">xyz close anchor tag**, 
when csv[i] is this data i get an error Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure CsvReader.Resources.ExceptionMessage.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "CsvReader" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
File G:data.CSV has been parsed  Successfully in 0 Seconds
Press any key to continue . . .

but if i have a field say(after removing double quote for links)
**"open anchor tag href=http://abc.html target=_blank>xyz close anchor tag**
Then it works . Please Provide Solution Without Removing double Quotes as Above.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2008/10/14/regex-pattern-for-parsing-csv-files-with-embedded-commas-dou.html

Comment: ps. one other thing to be wary of - some csv formats allow new line characters within quoted strings, some don't.

Comment: And what specific `CsvReader` are you using?

Comment: Are you saying that if the original line contains embedded quotes, then the CsvReader throws an exception? Or are you saying that trying to read the transformed line throws an exception? Or are you saying something entirely different? On what line does the error occur?

Comment: @JimMischel Fast CsvReader , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: @JimMischel if i have somthing like this "<a href="abc.html"></a>" then error , no error if its like this  "<a href=abc.html></a>" so saying that if the original line contains embedded quotes, then the CsvReader throws an exception

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But do you get an error trying to read that from the CSV file? Does the error occur when you call `ReadNextRecord`? Unless you tell us *where* the problem exists, we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @JimMischel yea . when ReadNextRecord is parsed it goes till str=csv[i] then it throws an error . i have put the code in try and catch . what u see there is the exception message.

Comment: Most likely the CsvReader doesn't like nested quotes. You'd have to look at the source code to see for sure. If that's the case, you'll either have to fix that or massage your data. Or use something like what's described in the link posted with the first column.

Comment: @JimMischel  yea . trying to but stuck with it for almost 2 days.

Comment: @JimMischel i Cannot change the data , because i have large amount of data .

Comment: It is easier to modify your data than to modify other's code.